# SQL Server LIKE statement with multiple values?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, database

Forgive if the question is repeated, I'm new to this site.

Been trying to create a search text box for a program that saved and organized documents. The software is database-based, and it can search for only one column at a time. I need it to look for any info in any column (expect date).

Here is the code:

```
private void textBox2_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        DataView vista = new DataView(tablaSql);
        vista.RowFilter = string.Format("asunto_corres LIKE'%{0}%'", textBox2.Text);
        dgTodo.DataSource = vista;
}
```

It works but only with the name of the column specified.

Any help to make this textbox look for info in any field/column.

Thanks

Comment: You have to build that _SQL-like_ column by column (with a long `OR`). **BUT**: 1) you can do it inspecting schema (no need to hard code all columns) and 2) use _SQL_ parameters, do not build SQL commands with user inputs (what about _SQL_ injection?).

Comment: @Adriano in this context the SQL Injection is not a concern (the RowFilter works on the in memory view)

Comment: You can use CONTAINS and FREETEXT clauses of Full-Text Search engine, but that can be overhead if your search is a small piece of app.

Comment: @Steve the point here is not (just) malicious SQL code but text that will make code fail (for example a search for a string like `Andrew's cat`). I mentioned SQL Injection because it's an easy search topic for Google if he need to search for that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try:

```
vista.RowFilter = string.Format("{0} LIKE'%{1}%'", fieldName, textBox2.Text);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by adding some "OR" operators:

```
vista.RowFilter = string.Format("asunto_corres LIKE'%{0}%' OR Column2 LIKE'%{0}%' OR ...", textBox2.Text);
```